# shape_clustering error while training tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

While training tesseract, an error is shown while doing shapeclustering step. Windows is showing a dialog box saying 'shape clustering training for tesseract has stopped working'. Image is attached below. How can i overcome this?